# Get Laravel route with optional parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, optional-parameters

I was wondering if it's possible to get the full url/path in Laravel with a optional parameter in it.

In web.php I have this:

```
Route::get('/blabla/{var1}/blabla/{var2?}', [Controller::class, 'function'])->name('myroute');
```

And want to get the full url/path with this:

```
echo route('myroute', 'var1', 'var2');
```

But only 'var1' appears. How come? In the manual there are no examples.

Comment: could you share your controller code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters should be in an array like:

```
echo route('myroute', ['var1', 'var2']);
```